# UITableViewCell subclassed, when selected disappears UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell, is working fine, when selected, it have a custom cell color and text color and stays selected until other cell is selected.

The problem is that, I have in this cell a UIImageView,  when the cell is not selected it shows, but if the cell is selected, the UIImageView disappears,

this is my code,

```
#import "MMSideDrawerTableViewCell.h"

@implementation MMSideDrawerTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {


        UIView * backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [backgroundView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];


        [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0
                                                           green:79.0/255.0
                                                            blue:80.0/255.0
                                                           alpha:1.0]];

        [self setBackgroundView:backgroundView];

        UIView *sa = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 4, 20, 20)];
        sa.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:sa];

        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor
                                      colorWithRed:230.0/255.0
                                      green:236.0/255.0
                                      blue:242.0/255.0
                                      alpha:1.0]];
        [self.textLabel setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5]];
        [self.textLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
        [self.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];



        //highlited
         UIImageView *selectionColor = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

        self.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:49/255.0f green:101/255.0f blue:135/255.0f alpha:1];

     }
    return self; 
} 


@end
```

what is the problem?
how to have my image showing with selected cell?

edit,
if I comment the line for the background selected state, it still hides the icon uiImageView

```
    //self.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
```

thanks!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and I'm not seeing what you are. I don't see the image view when the cell is not selected, and I do when it's selected, which is just what you should see (it's easier to tell if you make the image view's background color red).

Comment: hi @rdelmar I want to see the image when selected and unselected, thanks

Comment: What image? Are you talking about selectionColor? Do you have an image in it?

Comment: hi, yes the UIImageView that I use as background for selected state, even if I coment this background color, it still doesnt show the uiimageV, thanks

Comment: Why would you expect to see an image view that you've set to be the selectedBackgroundView when the cell isn't selected? If you want to see an image view when the cell is selected or unselected, just add it as a subview.

Comment: hi, maybe I wasnt clear, I want to show this uiImageView with an icon image in the cell on not selected and selected state

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36500/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mako)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You custom view looks to be just a colored `UIView`.  When a `UITableViewcell` is selected, all subviews inside of it get their background color changed on highlight.  You would need to have something more than just a `UIView` with a set background color.  You would need a `UIImageView`, or some such thing.

Comment: hi, thanks, I tried this as well, I have commented the background for selected state but same problem, I have edited my question cheers

Comment: Have you tried using a solid color image as your custom view background, instead of just a color?  Or even using something like this?   self.customView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"]];

Comment: I tried your second suggestion, and it doesn't work, but using a solid color image in an image view does work. +1

Comment: Its good to know the other option doesn't work either.  Pretty weird behavior.  I'm glad the image option worked, though.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the info about cell subviews getting their background color changed on selection? I haven't seen that anywhere.

Comment: I don't know where it would be in the official documents.  I can't imagine them documenting something so quirky.  I think its more of a side effect of their attempts to keep something looking selectable, even when it gets cluttered up.